# How can I track a bug report in Apple’s Radar?

Tags: ios, apple-radar

There’s a feature I’d like to use on iOS. It has already been requested on Radar and people from Apple say that they will probably implement it. Is there a way to get to the particular bug report in Radar so that I can watch the progress? I know I can’t see other people’s bug reports on Radar. What if I file a duplicate bug report, will that let me know when the original bug closes? I know about [Open Radar](http://www.openradar.me/), but the request in question is not there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I browse other people's (Apple) bug reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144873/can-i-browse-other-peoples-apple-bug-reports)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Things changed since Brian's answer.

Apple added a new feature in BugReporter. If your bug is marked as a duplicate, a new section will appear that will show the state of the original bug report. You can then follow the state of your bug there.

[image: scrennshot bugreporter]

Answer (score 8):

When I've filed bugs in Radar, if they're a duplicate then they get marked as closed. In other words, you won't get status info on the original bug by filing a duplicate.

Apple doesn't expose their bug tracking database to the world for several reasons. Firstly, some recorded bugs contain private information from customers. Secondly, exposing their product's flaws to the world may have ramifications from a security standpoint. Opening up Radar to the public would make it impossible to privately disclose a vulnerability.

There may be other reasons too, but Apple's not talking about them. We all know how Apple can be with secrecy.

Comment: Does that mean, simply to say, I can NOT know if my duplicated bug were solved forever?