# What's the use of Open Radar?

Tags: ios, macos

I do submit bugs to Apple's bug reporter, but I have read that adding it to [Open Radar](http://www.openradar.me) is useful.

It's not clear to me what the purpose is of `Open Radar`, since it seems I can't "like" others' open radars...

So **What is the purpose of Open Radar?  Why does it matter if I submit here too?**

Comment: This question is better asked on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: you should look at the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727041/how-can-i-track-a-bug-report-in-apples-radar

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about submitting bugs to Apple.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The use of OpenRadar is that you can look for Radars. Apple does not allow access to its Radar database.

Comment: <rant>Don't suppose anyone knows why Apple doesn't allow visibility of it's Radar database.  The process obviously doesn't work if people have to duplicate them to OpenRadar just so others can get any visibility on issues.  I've had a number of bugs closed as duplicates by Apple at which point I have no visibility of the original issue in Radar and just have to hope something has been kept up to date in OpenRadar. 
 I've largely given up on submitting bugs to Apple because of this</rant>

Comment: I don't think submitting duplicate bugs is a waste of time. I think it signals to apple engineers how pervasive a bug is. A bug that gets submitted 1000 times is going to get more attention then a minor bug submitted by one person. Though it it unfortunate that duplicate bugs don't get merged so you can get notified when the issue is resolved.